# Getting all necessary props

Tags: garrys-mod

When playing custom Garry's mod maps, I find it quite annoying to have 3/4 of the items being the big bright red error prop, meaning that I don't have that thing in any of my owned games.

I do own Portal 1 and 2, L4D 2 and TF2, so I'm guessing all that stuff comes from Half-Life, that I do not own.

Is there some way to download all of these without buying HL and/or HL2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Garry's Mod only works with the props from the games you have installed, and as far as I know you have to own the games in order to have access to the content.

However, I'm sure if you were to [look hard enough and ask nicely](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3536/steam-item-giveaway-trading-thread), you'd be able to come up with a way to get some of these games without having to pay for them, or at the very least, at a significant discount.